# Can't add element to object in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i try to add card (i mean add element to empty array/object in map ).
Can't add element(card) to an empty lane.
Unable to match `lane.key` when the lane is empty.

This is my code :

`D_key` : lane key where the card should move.

`c_lane_key` : current lane key.

`c_cardKey` : current card key

```
moveCard(D_key, c_lane_key, c_cardKey) {

    let data = this.state.lanesData || [];
    let temp = {};
    const objLoop = data
        .map((lane, n) => {
            Object.keys(lane.cards || [])
                .map((_key) => {
                    if (_key === c_cardKey) {
                        temp = lane.cards[_key];
                        const _data1 = [...this.state.lanesData.map(lane => ({
                            cards: ((Object.keys(lane.cards || [])
                                    .map(_cards => {
                                        let temp_array = lane['cards'][_cards];
                                                                                    if (D_key === lane.key && temp !== "") { 
                                            lane.cards[c_cardKey] = temp; // to add card to cards{} in lane[]
                                            temp = "";
                                        temp_array['key_id'] = _cards;
                                        return temp_array;
                                    }))
                                .reduce((obj, card) => {
                                    obj[card.key_id] = { description: card.description, title: card.title }
                                    return obj;
                                }, {})
                            ),
                            id: lane.id,
                            key: lane.key,
                            label: lane.label,
                            title: lane.title
                        }))];

                        let _data2 = [...this.state.lanesData.map(lane => ({
                            cards: (Object.keys(lane.cards || [])
                                    .map(key => {
                                        let temp_array = lane.cards[key];
                                        temp_array['key_id'] = key;
                                        return temp_array;
                                    })
                                    .filter(card => D_key === lane.key || card.key_id !== c_cardKey)
                                )
                                .reduce((obj, card) => {
                                    obj[card.key_id] = { description: card.description, title: card.title }
                                    return obj;
                                }, {}),
                            id: lane.id,
                            key: lane.key,
                            label: lane.label,
                            title: lane.title
                        }))]

                        this.setState({ lanesData: _data1 },
                            () => {
                                this.setState({ lanesData: _data2 });
                            });
                    }
                })
        });}
```

This is how **`this.state.lanesData`** looks..

[image: this is data in format]

Answer (score 0):

would be good if you posted the raw code and not the transpiled one. in any case. you can't add elements during a map. Map is a transformation of element operation meaning you get to transform each element of the array but never the entire collection. If you are in need of doing this you should use `reduce`. this would allow you to transform both the elements and the collection at the same time.

```
  collection.reduce(function(newCollection, element, index){
    // do your thing here
    return newCollection

  }, [])
```

if you try to do

```
  collection.map(function(element, index, sameCollection)
  {
    // do your thing here
    collection.push('anything');
    // or
    sameCollection.push('anything)
  })
```

the resulting array won't have inserted elements but the original will, which should not be done.